# Paginating in ListView django

Tags: python, django

I am trying to paginate data in my table in html template, but it is not working. I am using default paginate system from list views. Also I have a form in which user can pass items per page value. This is my code for views.py:

```
class CategoryListView(ListView):
    model = Category

    def get_paginate_by(self, queryset, **kwargs):
        itemsForm = ItemsPerPageForm(self.request.GET)
        if itemsForm.is_valid():
            itemsPerPage = itemsForm.cleaned_data.get('items_per_page')
            print(itemsPerPage)
            if itemsPerPage is None:
                return 4
            else:
                if itemsPerPage > 0 and itemsPerPage <= Category.objects.get_queryset().count():
                    return itemsPerPage
                else:
                    return 4
    def get_context_data(self, *, object_list=Expense.objects.get_queryset(), **kwargs):
        categoriesList = Category.objects.get_queryset()
        queryset = object_list
        return super().get_context_data(
            noOfExpenses=zip(categoriesList, noOfExpenses(queryset)),
            itemsForm = ItemsPerPageForm
        )
```

And this is my django template:

```
</table>
<tbody>
    {% for category, expenses in noOfExpenses %}
      <tr>
        <td>{{ page_obj.start_index|add:forloop.counter0}}.</td>
        <td>{{ category.name|default:"-" }}</td>
        <td>{{ expenses }}</td>
      </tr>
    {% empty %}
      <tr>
        <td colspan="6">no items</td>
      </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</tbody>
</table>
<hr/>
    {% include "_pagination.html" %}
    {{page_obj}}
    <form method="get" action="">
    {{itemsForm.as_p}}
    <button type="submit">submit</button>
    </form>
```

And _pagination.html:

```
<div class="pagination">
    <span class="pagination__nav">
        {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
            <a href="?page=1">&laquo; first</a>
            <a href="?page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}">previous</a>
        {% endif %}

        <span class="current">
            Page {{ page_obj.number }} of {{ page_obj.paginator.num_pages }}.
        </span>
        {% if page_obj.has_next %}
            <a href="?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}">next</a>
            <a href="?page={{ page_obj.paginator.num_pages }}">last &raquo;</a>
        {% endif %}
    <br/> Total items: {{page_obj.paginator.count}}
    </span>
</div>
```

So in the end, on the website, despite that I have only 4 items, I have 2 pages in which items are numbered from 1-7 and they repeat. When I pass a value of 1 I have 4 pages, but the number of items doesn't change (still four in the table).

Comment: maybe you have to convert itemsPerPage to int

Comment: show us rest of your listview code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so I found the answer. The Generic Views in Django uses `object_list` as queryset. Then uses it to render out data from queryset. I needed to change `noOfExpenses` to be `object_list` and convert it to `list`, thats all.

Answer (score 1):

```
class MyView(ListView):
    template_name = "page.html"
    paginate_by = 4

    def get_paginate_by(self, queryset):
        itemsForm = ItemsPerPageForm(self.request.GET)
        if itemsForm.is_valid():
            itemsPerPage = itemsForm.cleaned_data.get('items_per_page')
            itemsPerPage = int(itemsPerPage)
            print(itemsPerPage)
            if  itemsPerPage > 0 and itemsPerPage <= Category.objects.get_queryset().count():
                    self.request.session['paginate_by'] = itemsPerPage
                else:
                    self.request.session['paginate_by'] = self.paginate_by
        return self.request.GET.get('paginate_by', self.paginate_by)
```

in your template:
just display this **paginate_by** session

Comment: Right, It worked, it shows now page 1 out of 1. But still, after passing a number of items per page, it still shows 4 items, even when number of pages change.

Comment: You can save this variable to session and view it in your template, I changed the code (not tested) hope it will work.

Comment: Well, the number of items still doesn't change. I don't know, maybe its problem with my template, maybe I forgot to include something in `for loop`. It's like this `for loop` iterate always four times, even if the number of items per page is changed. Maybe there is a function that breakes the loop or iterate only `items_per_page` times?

Comment: could you please share your view?

Answer (score 0):

you can get the **paginate_by** value by use:

```
page_obj.paginator.per_page
```